# cmd и node.js подружить кодировки

Tags: node.js, кодировка, cmd, iconv

```
require('child_process').execFile('cmd.bat', { detached: true }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Вместо stdout вылазят вопросительные знаки.

Пробовал iconv-lite, как-то получилось, а сейчас я забыл что делал (((

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Вот же пример у них перекодируй вывод попробуй так точно не уверен нет под рукой

```
    console.log('start app  (%s%s; node %s; pid:%s)',process.platform, process.arch, process.version, process.pid);

iconv.extendNodeEncodings();

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var pr    = spawn('test.bat');

//пробую все возможные варианты:
var enca = ['UTF8','utf8','utf-8','866','cp866','CP866','CP-866','cp-866','cp 866','CP 866','dos','dos866','dos-866','OEM','OEM866','OEM-866'];
for(var i=0;i<enca.length;i++){
  var enc = enca[i];
  var is_err = 0;
  try {
    pr.stdout.setEncoding(enc);
  } catch(err) {
    is_err = 1;
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (!is_err) console.log('work: ' + enc);
}


pr.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: Ну в cmd кодировка же cp866? Всё равно не получается!
¤¤¤ ¤ ¤¤¤й¤е C ¤¤¤¤¤ ¤¤¤¤ System
 ¤¤)¤¤ ¤¤¤¤¤ м¤: 5866-BDC5

 ¤¤¤¤и¤¤¤ ¤¤¤¤¤ C:\dev\sys\rcmd

20.01.2020  22:18    <DIR>          .
20.01.2020  22:18    <DIR>          ..
21.01.2020  15:03               844 app.js
21.01.2020  15:04                43 cmd.bat
20.01.2020  21:32                33 exec.js
19.01.2020  16:41                 2 name.txt
20.01.2020  20:24               719 server.js
               5 )¤¤¤          1¤641 ¤¤¤¤
               2 ¤¤¤¤¤  109¤177¤626¤624 ¤¤¤¤ о¤¤¤¤¤

Comment: попробуй добавить 
iconv.extendNodeEncodings();

Comment: start app  (win32ia32; node v12.3.0; pid:7964)
ACTION NEEDED: require('iconv-lite').extendNodeEncodings() is not supported in your version of Node
See more info at https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Node-v4-compatibility
work: UTF8
work: utf8
work: utf-8
остальные не подошли, и вместо русских букв знаки вопроса ((

Comment: Я точно помню недавно получалось, было типа как в сначала в ответе, вроде бы или просто одной функцией, сейчас всё перепробовал, и никак!

Comment: Попробуй поменять кодировку консоли добавив chcp 65001 https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2190  там есть пример и тут посмотри https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation/issues/317

Comment: Тоже посмотри https://github.com/nickkolok/node-autodetect-utf8-cp1251-cp866

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103543/discussion-between---and-max-nest).